How is projective measurement usually handled in matrix product state-based simulators?
I decided to write my own matrix product state (MPS)-based quantum circuit simulator. I've got my head all wrapped around the usual things for this like gate application and how Schmidt decomposition plays into everything, but I'm having trouble implementing single-qubit mid-circuit measurements.
More specifically, I want to implement something that takes some $N$-qubit state $\left| \psi \right\rangle$ and randomly projects the $k$-th qubit into either $\left| 0 \right\rangle$ or $\left| 1 \right\rangle$ with probabilities $\left| \left\langle 0_k \middle| \psi \right\rangle \right|^2$ and $\left| \left\langle 1_k \middle| \psi \right\rangle \right|^2$, as you'd usually expect, and then continues applying gates afterward. The trouble is, I can't think of a way to do this properly (i.e. in a way that captures all the usual behaviors that come from entanglement) without contracting the whole state into a full $N$-rank tensor (or equivalent), doing the projection there, and then re-factoring back into the MPS (which is obviously a very expensive computation).
So the bottom line is: what's the better strategy? (Is there even one?)
EDIT: More detail on my setup... The MPS I'm working with is a so-called canonical form that maintains the singular values of each of the SVDs used to factor the original state on each bond index. Ideally, the strategy for applying measurements should be able to modify the singular values so that they can easily be used for e.g. state compression/approximation and calculations of entanglement entropies.

This is nothing but applying a non-unitary gate, and unitarity should not play a too important role in those simulations. Or is the problem not the projection, but determining the probabilties?

Hm, I hadn't expected that just applying a jump operator to a single site's tensor would work, but I just tried it and it did... Thanks for the sanity check.
I didn't mention this explicitly in the original post, but I'm working in a canonical form with singular values held in their own data structures (so I can easily calculate entanglement entropies), and ideally I'd be able to update them with each measurement, which doesn't happen automatically when I just apply jump operators. Do you have any insight for how to manage those without doing a whole refactor?

So for instance, I can take an initial $\left| 000 \right\rangle$ state, apply $\text{CNOT} \cdot H$ on the first two qubits, and then on the second qubits, and this leaves me with singular values $[1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}]$ on both internal bonds. If I then measure the middle qubit, it should reduce the singular values on both bonds, but, of course, doesn't when I only apply the jump operator.

And, thinking about this a little more, merely applying a jump operator to a single site doesn't properly project an entangled pair into the correct two-qubit state on its own...

(1) It indeed requires updating the canonical form. The local update in TEBD only works for unitary evolution. But that's how it is, and this scales only linearly in $n$. (2) You have to apply the operator you want to apply. Then you get the state you get after applying the operator you want to apply. (3) The question for your simulation, still, is how to compute the probability. Do you know how to compute norms of MPS?

What do you mean by (2) and (3)? Are you saying that to get the right behavior for (e.g. measurement of a Bell state) I'd need to essentially apply a multi-qubit jump operator? As for the last bit, are the norms/probabilities not simply the contraction of the MPS with its conjugate? (Up to a square root, I guess.)

I don't know what behavior you want, so I can't tell you what operator to apply. But if you want to do a projective measurement in the |0> |1> basis, then you will have to apply |0><0| or |1><1| to that qubit. As for your 2nd point, yes.

To be more specific about my desires behavior-- suppose I have a two-qubit state, $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$. In the canonical MPS, there are two non-zero singular values on the bond joining the two qubits, both equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$. I would like to perform a single-qubit measurement on the first qubit, and then another on the second qubit. I should get an outcome of either 0 or 1 from the first qubit, and the outcome of the second should always agree with the first.

But, applying only a single-qubit projection operator to the first qubit updates neither the singular values nor the description of the second qubit' state. So when I go to then measure the second qubit afterward, the outcome will not correlate with that of the first. If I try to calculate some property of the bond between them, the calculation will also be wrong. Scaling up to $N$ qubits, where there may be some entanglement between qubits on opposite ends of the MPS, is the only way to get this correlated behavior (with updated singular values) to contract the whole MPS and re-do all SVDs?

Basically, yes.

Would you mind elaborating? I feel like there must be some other effective way to do (something like) this, since people apparently use MPSs to calculate things like measurement-induced phase transitions, which seem to require the above.

It is efficient: It scales linearly with $n$, rather than exponentially as a brute force simulation would. (Getting an MPS into can form is linear in n.)

...$n$ being the number of qubits? How is that? Bond dimensions are in general exponential in $n$, which means that all the SVDs required to get to canonical form must also be exponential, right?

If your bond dimension is exponential, well, then you are exponential anyway. The bond dimension also enters with the third power, yes. But this is unaviodable.
